# naming static int variables

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions

I have quite a number of integer variables (most of them static, some non-static) in my code. Since am working on ajax testing, getting rid of these variables is not possible. Currently I use "int" prefixed to a word that matches the context where the variable is used. But too much of that makes my code look odd.
For eg. I need to press cancel button whose id gets incremented with each run. So am using a static variable and I named it

`static int intCancel;`

Is there any particular pattern in which the variables can be named so as to make the code more readable?

Comment: I would consider making them instance fields, even if you only need one instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common misconception is that variable names must be short. Consider expanding them to state what they are. IDEs make completing variable names easy. So `numberTimesCancelSelected` might be an option.

Consider reading [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GSTOAM) for a better discussion of this topic.

Comment: Not to mention prefixing variable name with the variable type stopped being trendy in the 90s...

Comment: @Romain...yes, thanks to intellisense. If you're in an ide which doesn't have intellisense I can still see a value in this.

Comment: Ok. So I will expand the variable names and be more specific. Also, there are so many count variables like i, iter, iterator, count, c etc etc. Any comments on generalizing those? To add on, due to the same reason of in need of static ones, I can't use the same count variable in all those contexts.

Comment: generally, most people stick with `i,j,k` for `for` loops but being in the practice of using something better is a good idea. Outside for loops, all variables should have a meaningful name. One idea might be `currentIndex`

Comment: so again, I have a locator variable which is much frequently reassigned with a new xpath. Reassigning does not affect the functionality but sometimes after some return statements, even I get confused which locator assignment I must look at. Should I reuse the variable or create different string variables? I know am being stupid, I just want to know what veterans do.

Comment: If you as the producer are getting confused by what can be assigned to the variable, sounds like multiple variables would be a good idea. Better yet, is there a redesign of the method that would limit it to doing just one thing?

Answer (score 1):

In the C# world, there are tools such as Resharper and even Microsoft's Visual Studio itself which are quite happy to impose naming conventions upon you. This is a great approach because it means that everybody cranks out consistent-looking code, and a lot of the "subjectivity" is taken out.

Now Resharper and Visual Studio both apply different rules (to each other), but that's not really the point. The point is that you pick a convention and you stick with it. Be it camel case (which is what I typically use these days, and which is what I'd recommend to you if you're stuck for choice) or hungarian (which I would have used fifteen years ago), or whatever. Just pick one and be consistent, this way your code is more maintainable, and that's the holy grail imo.

I agree with the earlier comments about naming things appropriately (abbreviating names or making them obscure is just lazy), and by all means use enums where appropriate (although I suspect you just gave that as an example). But whatever you do, pick a convention and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The Hungarian notation is a standard for naming variables:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

In your case would be:

```
static int iCancel
```

Comment: It is a standard that has "stopped being trendy in the 90s" as Romain stated above. It is a style that should be avoided.

Comment: lots of people found it useful a number of years ago, the trend now is to avoid it. According to Robert Martin, ".. nowadays HN and other forms of type encoding are simply impediments. They make it harder to change the name or type of a variable, function, member or class. They make it harder to read the code. And they create the possibly that the encoding system will mislead the reader."

Comment: With any IDE you can refactor a variable or method name quikly, but I don't intend to dicuss about this. For me is more readable shorter names with a little type notation, specially in Java.

Comment: In the ide I use most (visual studio) I just need to hover the mouse over a variable to see its type. I get no added value whatsoever from building the type into the variable's name. Unless I suppose I wanted to get a hardcopy and read a bunch of code on the train for the heck of it!